# The underlying provider failed on Open - Kigg Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kigg

I have downloaded Kigg Asp.net Starter Kit Project.

I then converted it to VS.Net 2010 Project, It did everything successfully.

I then run create kigg database and also added default data. (From the script file which comes along with source)

**My Dev Environment
- 64 bit Win 7 OS, with VS.Net 2010 and SQL Server 2008**

But i am still getting this error.

```
The underlying provider failed on Open.

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

Source: System.Data.Entity

StackTrace:
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__1[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
   at System.Data.Objects.CompiledQuery.ExecuteQuery[TResult](ObjectContext context, Object[] parameterValues)
   at System.Data.Objects.CompiledQuery.Invoke[TArg0,TArg1,TResult](TArg0 arg0, TArg1 arg1)
   at Kigg.EF.Repository.UserRepository.FindByUserName(String userName) in D:\DevEnv\Source\EntityFramework\Repository\UserRepository.cs:line 94
   at Kigg.Repository.DecoratedUserRepository.FindByUserName(String userName) in D:\DevEnv\Source\Core\Repository\Decorated\DecoratedUserRepository.cs:line 41
   at Kigg.Repository.LoggingUserRepository.FindByUserName(String userName) in D:\DevEnv\Source\Core\Repository\Decorated\Logging\LoggingUserRepository.cs:line 59
   at Kigg.Repository.DecoratedUserRepository.FindByUserName(String userName) in D:\DevEnv\Source\Core\Repository\Decorated\DecoratedUserRepository.cs:line 41
   at Kigg.Infrastructure.CreateDefaultUsers.CreateUserIfNotExists(DefaultUser defaultUser) in D:\DevEnv\Source\Core\Infrastructure\Bootstrapper\CreateDefaultUsers.cs:line 37
   at Kigg.EnumerableExtension.ForEach[T](IEnumerable`1 enumerable, Action`1 action) in D:\DevEnv\Source\Core\Extension\EnumerableExtension.cs:line 14
   at Kigg.Infrastructure.CreateDefaultUsers.Execute() in D:\DevEnv\Source\Core\Infrastructure\Bootstrapper\CreateDefaultUsers.cs:line 28
   at Kigg.Infrastructure.Bootstrapper.<Run>b__0(IBootstrapperTask t) in D:\DevEnv\Source\Core\Infrastructure\Bootstrapper\Bootstrapper.cs:line 21
   at Kigg.EnumerableExtension.ForEach[T](IEnumerable`1 enumerable, Action`1 action) in D:\DevEnv\Source\Core\Extension\EnumerableExtension.cs:line 14
   at Kigg.Infrastructure.Bootstrapper.Run() in D:\DevEnv\Source\Core\Infrastructure\Bootstrapper\Bootstrapper.cs:line 21
   at Kigg.Web.GlobalApplication.OnStart() in D:\DevEnv\Source\Web\Global.asax.cs:line 11
   at Kigg.Web.GlobalApplication.Application_Start() in D:\DevEnv\Source\Web\Global.asax.cs:line 23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is unable to find your sql server. please check your connection string in web.config

Comment: visit http://kigg.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Deployment%20Guide%20Part%201&referringTitle=Documentation for detail

Comment: Thanks, but I have followed all steps in documentation still i am getting same error.  I know it would be very silly mistake but since i am new to MVC could you please guide me.  Thanks